# Парсинг динамических контента биржи Binance

Tags: python, парсер, http, requests, bs4

Мне необходимо получить список всех пар [криптовалюта/USDT](https://www.binance.com/en/markets/spot-USDT) на бирже Binance.

Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью requests и bs4.

Проблема заключается в том, что на странице выводится лишь 50 пар. При подгрузке следующих 50 пар вместо изменения страницы происходит просто изменение контента, насколько я понимаю. При этом в инструментах разработчика во вкладке Network наблюдается POST запрос с ответом в виде:

```
{"success":true,"code":0,"msg":"OK","data":null}
```

Я не могу понять, где именно в данных запрашиваются следующие 50 пар и как можно получить информацию стразу о всех парах. Прошу знающих подсказать, как именно решить проблему или в какую сторону необходимо смотреть.

Comment: Не это вы ищете? https://www.binance.com/bapi/earn/v1/public/indicator/abnormal-trading-notice/pageList?pageIndex=1&pageSize=100&startTime=1653503342625&endTime=1653589742625

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то это перечень всех существующих пар (включая btc, busd и т.д.), но это также решает мою проблему. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как вы добрались до этих данных?

Comment: Там хитрость :) https://ibb.co/Yf9pfwq смотрите pending запросы, если я верно понял это вебсокеты (да, там именно вебсокеты)

Comment: 'как вы добрались до этих данных?" Так же как и вы до своих данных.

Comment: Теперь все стало понятно, большое спасибо. Нужно было смотреть не запросы, которые приходят при обновлении контента, а на те запросы, которые осуществляются при загрузке всей страницы

Comment: Точно, именно так- вебсокеты создаются и происходит подписка на события в самом начале, при загрузке страницы. Кроме того, это же публичное и задокументированное API, если я правильно понимаю